# Locate the end of an XZ stream

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, xz

I am currently trying to extract the inital RAM filesystem that is embedded in a kernel image, modify it, and repack the kernel image with it. You can search GitHub and find several projects that do this [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=site:github.com+repack+initramfs+zimage). My problem with those scripts is that they are very specific or turn out to hard code values that I cannot use with the kernel image I am working with or they are just hard to reverse engineer. The kernel image I am working with uses XZ to compress the kernel and GZip to compress the initial RAM filesystem CPIO archive. The end of a GZip stream is easy to locate by looking for a particular string and those GitHub projects seem to need to know the exact end of these streams.

I am able to extract the compressed portion of the kernel like this:

```
offset=$(cat zImage | grep -aob $'\xFD\x37\x7A\x58\x5A\x00' | cut -d ":" -f 1 | sed -n 2p)
dd bs=1 skip=$offset if=zImage | xzcat > Image
```

I can then extract the initial RAM filesystem CPIO archive from `Image` like this:

```
offset=$(cat "${1}" | grep -aob $'\x1F\x8B\x08' | cut -d ":" -f 1 | sed -n 2p)
dd bs=1 skip=$offset if=Image | zcat > initramfs.cpio
```

Now, it seems from reading those GitHub scripts that one must know the end address of the compressed streams. How do I find the end of an XZ stream in shell script?

Answer (score 2):

The size of an xz file or stream is encoded within the `Unpadded Size` field within the xz header.
The `Unpadded size` field indicates the size of the Block **excluding** the `Block Padding` field.

> i.e. **Unpadded Size** = size-of( Block Header + Compressed Data + CRC fields)

---

One quick method to obtain the size is using the [**xz** tool](https://linux.die.net/man/1/xz) itself as follows:

```
xz --robot --list <xz-file-or-stream> | cut -f 4 | sed -n 2p
```

Reference: The [**xz file-format**](https://tukaani.org/xz/xz-file-format.txt).

---

<sub>**Note:** Unpadded Size is stored using the encoding described in **Section 1.2 Multibyte Integers** of the xz file-format specification.
The value MUST never be zero; with the current structure of Blocks, the actual minimum value for `Unpadded Size` field is five.</sub>

<sub>**Implementation note**: Because the size of the Block Padding field is not included in Unpadded Size, calculating the total size of a Stream or doing random-access reading requires calculating the actual size of the Blocks by rounding Unpadded Sizes up to the next multiple of four.</sub>